# Given two files find words in file1 but not in file2

Tags: java, algorithm

Given two files come up with an algorithm/program to find words in file1, but not in file2.
Note that the **words in file are not in sorted order**.

This is my thought process:

- Step 1: Read and add the words of file2 to a HashSet
- Step 2: Read file1 and check if a word of of file1 is 'not' present in HashSet. Then add it to the list of words present in file1 but not in file2.

This algorithm will work fine if the number of words in both the files is few 100s or 1000s.
However, if both the files are huge (billions of words), then this solution will not work, so I came up with an improved solution:

- Step 1: Read file2 word by word and sort words alphabetically assign buckets to words, say one bucket for all words starting with 'a'.

So the map will look like this ['a':{'ample','and'...}]. This will help me in searching for bucket within log(n) time complexity and then log(n) to find if the word is contained within the sorted list.

- Step 2: Read file1 and check if a word of file1 does not have a bucket or is not within the list contained in the bucket.

This solution will work, but i believe there is still scope for improvement.
How can this solution be improved further?

Comment: I would let Java's hashing a chance to give good performances also for billions of keys, before I would look for a much more complex and not intuitive solution

Comment: You could use a database instead of a HashSet.  That should be able to deal with much larger volumes of data.

Comment: With billions of words, your problem will be to hold everything in memory. If you have enough memory, then the HashSet solution will be much, much faster. If you don't have enough memory, then use a database.

Comment: And, BTW, You'll probably never have billions of distinct words. Even when you take all the plural forms, etc. English has much much less words than that, and your file probably uses a tiny subset.

Comment: @JBNizet, I agree with the logic, but words can be noun as well. So it can easily run to a number which will not fit into RAM.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language says that the Second Edition of the **20-volume** Oxford English Dictionary contains full entries for 171,476 words in current use. That's very, very, very far from billions. Assume your text contains 200,000 distinct words (which is probably not the case), and assume the average size to hold each word is 100 bytes, that makes only 20 MBs of memory. And anyway, if it does not fit in RAM, your alternative slow solution won't work either, so you'd still want a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use some [external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) to sort both files, and then iterate them in parallel to find a word that appear only in file 1:

Pseudo code (after sorting):

```
iter1 = 0
iter2 = 0
while iter1 < file1.length:
    if file1[iter1] == file2[iter2]:
         iter1 = iter1 + 1
         iter2 = iter2 + 1
    else if file1[iter1] > file2[iter2]:
         iter2 = iter2 + 1
    else: //we know for sure the item is only in file1
         iter1 = iter1 + 1
         yield file1[iter1]
```

This solution takes `O(nlogn)` time, and very little space needed (the amount of space needed for the external sort).

Also note, this problem is a variant of [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), so most likely it has lower bound of `Omega(nl0gn)` when using comparisons based algorithm, or Omega(n) time + space for using hashing.

Comment: O(nlogn) is potentially slower than using hash tables. OPs problem is that he misunderstands something in hash tables.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Yes, it is - it's a tradeoff, you are probably going to need linear space or O(nlogn) time, due to relatedness to element distinctness problem. if linear space is a problem - you are going to need O(nlogn) solution.

Comment: Yes, it's true about the tradeoff, but according to OPs second algorithm he still holds everything in memory.

Comment: @amit, appreciate the answer, so the conclusion is if the data set is small it makes sense to use a HashSet as its time complexity is O(1); better performance . But if the data set is huge and cannot fit into memory then we need to use external sorting and comparison.